# I can't share a WordPress site's link in Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, url, share, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to share my website's link in facebook but I can't do it.

The website is done with WordPress and I am using the plugin Open Graph, but at the end I get a different error message:

**Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.**
OR
**Query Error Error performing query**
OR
**You can't share this link**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like your domain was blocked. Link to let them know you think this is wrong is right in the message. (Don’t expect that to have an effect if only you submit it once though - ideally other users wanting to share this would tell Facebook as well.)

Comment: thank you for your reply .but i can share the simple link lik this :nnhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813780/ .the probleme that i can't see  the pic of the link

Comment: It might only have blocked partial URLs, the screenshot suggests that everything located under your wp-content folder might be blocked.

Comment: ok thank you again .